# Please help me draw a simplified small signal model for this circuit

Tags: electronics

I have an assignment that requires me to design a multistage amplifier with a minimum gain of 35 db and a load of 8 ohm. This circuit meets those conditions but I'm not sure on how to draw the small signal model.
[image]

Here's what I came up with so far.[image]

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. You need to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself. Show us all of your work and then ask a specific question. In this case, you need to try to create a small-signal model and show us what you came up with.

Comment: no, below is the place for an answer, not for your question

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the additional information.